# How to extract two different elements using one JSON path extractor.

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to extract two elements from response for this purpose Im using JSON path extractor in Jmeter. Right now I am extracting these two elements by using TWO extractor for each element.
Can i do the same by using only one extractor.I am attaching picture for reference Please let me know where I am wrong. As this is not working for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `semicolon (;)` to add one or more `JSON Path expressions` and `Variable names` and other applicable fields, in order to capture them in one [JSON PATH Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).

From official docs:

Variable Names

> Semi-colon separated names of variables that will contain the results
>   of JSON-PATH expressions (must match number of JSON-PATH expressions)

JSON Path Expressions

> Semi-colon separated JSON-PATH expressions (must match number of
>   variables)

Similarly for `Match Numbers` and `Default Values` fields.

Image reference:
[image]

Comment: Still did not work for me... Not sure what's wrong. Are Match Numbers and Default Values mandatory?

Comment: Could not guess what went wrong. please post a new question with your specific data and setup made. Ideally, we use Match Numbers, in case if you are expecting more than one match and pick the value from that list.    Now, please use JSON Extractor whihc is updated one in latest JMeter version https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

Comment: I am observing same issue with Jmeter version 4.0 71823414. I don't see http request with json post extractor on the view summary tree as well, may be multiple variable capture broken in this specific release